# ajax запрос в базу данных

Tags: php, ajax

Доброго времени суток всем есть скрипт добавления в БД с помощью ajax,

```
   //форма регистрации
   <?php 
date_validate();
?>

    // сам ajax запрос
        $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#send_to_base").click(function (e) { 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var login = $('#login').val();
                        $.ajax({  
                            type: "POST",  
                            url: "add_to_base.php",
                            data:{login:login},
                            cache: false,
                        success: function(response){

                        }   
                        });
                    });

            });
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//add_to_base.php
$login = $_POST['login'];
    function date_validate(){                   
            global $connection;     
            //здесь будет валидация полей
                        $query = array (
                            'username'    => trim($login));
                        register_user($query);**//функция добавления в БД**


    }
```

Вопрос таков почему в функции **date_validate()** скрипт не работает??, если в функцию не заключать то работает.
Как сделать что ajax видел функцию **date_validate()**???

Comment: потому что функцию надо вызвать `date_validate()`

Comment: вызывается функция, без ajax работает, с ajax нужно название функции убирать и оставлять код без нее

Comment: `вызывается функция` - где? ............... `с ajax нужно название функции убирать и оставлять код без нее` - что? кто говорил про название функции в ajax?

Comment: `$login = $_POST['login'];    date_validate($login ); function date_validate($login){ { ` - вы не передаете login  в функцию

Comment: так тоже не выходит, не зависимо передаешь или нет

Comment: вы именно так сделали, как сейчас у меня в комментарии?

Comment: да именно так и сделал

Comment: сделайте `print_r($query);` - есть значение там?

Comment: почему вы `date_validate` вызываете в файле с ajax, а не в `add_to_base.php` ? О_О

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, в add_to_base.php я ее и вызываю (там и сам ajax находится ниже в тегах javascript),

Comment: splash58, Array ( [username] => ) выводит на экран, но если просто на форме нажимать F5 то в БД добавляются пустые записи, а с формы не хотят

Comment: Если после Array ( [username] => введенный логин, разбирайтесь с функцией register_user, если ничего, то еще раз посмотрите мой комментарий

Comment: вот так - вызываете функцию после получения значения, и передаете в нее логин `$login = $_POST['login']; date_validate($login ); function date_validate($login){`

Comment: splash58, вызывал и так, и как только не вызывал, не работает(